# How to build web applications with hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

So I have to build a project in hyperledger for medical supply chain where we will be tracking counterfeit drugs. For that I have downloaded the necessary files etc. I really don't know how to build a supply chain project in hyperledger fabric.

1. I want to know if I can build a web application in hyperledger fabric.
2. Is it possible to integrate qr code system and IPFS with the project.
   So if you can please guide me on how to get started with building a small demo of supply chain it would be really helpful. Thanks.

I have tried to run the test network but it shows the error: Unable to find image 'hyperledger/fabric-tools:latest' locally docker: Error response from daemon: manifest for hyperledger/fabric-tools:latest not found.
After this I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

1. Typically you would use a Fabric SDK to build an API and then any web/mobile app to contact the API. It's possible to use an SDK in a web app, but a bit of a pain.
2. Yes. But those are immaterial to fabric. Just use them as you normally would in any app.
3. Make sure you have the prerequisites installed. I have never seen '/network.sh up' fail to download images. Absent more info I have no clue.